# How to set https in react-boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-boilerplate

i'm starting a new project with https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate, and i need use https, i already configure nginx to https, my custom nginx config file is here:

https://www.pastiebin.com/5b034ba8938b3

I run my app with `npm run start` and when i access http://localhost:3000 it works fine.

When i tried to access with https://localhost/voos/ the content doesnt load:

[image]

I already configure my localhost to use https.

Comment: react-boilerplate uses webpack-dev-server to serve files, so you could try looking at webpack-dev-server's docs: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server . nginx won't have anything to do with local development. Is there a reason you need https for local host? Usually you don't need to worry about https until you deploy to production.

Comment: I was able to set up https with nginx. I needed this to try facebook login.